# Facebook like button only works once then disappears

Tags: html, caching, facebook-like

This is quite strange but I'm sure someone can explain it to me (hopefully).
WEBSITE: http://www.maschineuk.com

PROBLEM: the like button works at first but if you then refresh the page (or go onto another page and then back to the homepage), the like button disappears.

NOTE: The like button DOES re-appear if I clear my cache... anyone understand what is going on here? Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

p.s. sorry about the messy code...

Answer (score 0):

Your website works fine in my browser..
Though to stop caching on your page you can use HTML headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />  
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />  
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)